# Listview Row is not showing full element

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have listview in which I am setting six different things. And that is working awesome on normal size devices. But its gets chopped off from the last item of the single row that is Text view.

I do not understand why it is happening I have Used linear layouts. And why it is only getting chopped off in the large size devices like Samsung Tab 7"  and 10"
although normal devices are showing it good.

> **Edit One :  This is design of my Listview Row**

Here is what my Layout of listview looks a like.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="20">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_row_customer_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/accepted_offer_text_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Customer Name Goes Here"
                android:textColor="#ffa123"
                android:textSize="@dimen/accepted_offer_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_offer_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dialog_offer_name"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Offer Name Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Email Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_phone_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/call"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Phone Number Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pin"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Address Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_c_brand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cofin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=" Brand Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_offer_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clock"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Start-End Time Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="                       "
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_row_total_person"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/no_of_persons"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="aa" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_row_total_acceptors"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/acceptors"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="aa" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/calander_upper"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_row_month"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="aa"
                                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_accept_offer_tvcontent_size" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_row_day"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/calander_lower"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="0dp"
                            android:text="aa"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_accept_offer_tvcontent_size" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> I added the Last textview empty so that it can be gets chopped off. but has no effect. I have debug my code and saw that in adapter the last textview is truly initialized and then the last textview gets the data. but its still not visible or chopped off.

Please help me just this minor problem is keeping me away to complete the app.

Comment: add a screenshot also

Answer (score 0):

try to add "scrollView" so if your layout is not fit on any device it will scroll otherwise use weight in your layout so it will adjust according to each screen size. if you not understand you can ask question in comments, I will explain about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="20">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_row_customer_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Customer Name Goes Here"
                android:textColor="#ffa123" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_offer_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Offer Name Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Email Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_phone_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Phone Number Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Address Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_c_brand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=" Brand Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/row_offer_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Start-End Time Goes here"
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="                       "
                    android:textColor="#AAAAAA" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_row_total_person"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="aa" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_row_total_acceptors"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="aa" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_row_month"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="aa"
                                android:paddingTop="2dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_row_day"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_row_month"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="0dp"
                            android:text="aa" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I changed something

Comment: you have done nothing but eliminating drawable left item from the textview